# How can I search Outlook, ignoring all emails in a particular folder?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

In my case, I need to search for an email from a specific person.  However, this individuals user account is also associated with an auto-email process I have 1,000's of emails from this person, because of this process.

All of these emails are being copied, and marked as read, into a folder that I mostly ignore.  When I attempt to search my email by this user's email address, I see these thousands of emails, and our former conversations are dispersed amongst these emails.

How can I search for this user, ignoring all emails within the folder that is catching all of the auto-emails that are being sent by this users email account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Search Folder that uses advanced criteria to include messages from all folders in your mailbox *except* the folder you wish to exclude, then perform your search inside of that search folder.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into that.  Sorry, this sounds like a simple solution.  I'm semi-new to Outlook (because I had to use Lotus for the first 10 years of my career!)  Thank you.